# How to automatically filter a DropDown List values based on selected textbox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an asp.net page with two DropDown List populating values from the same table in the Database where a user is required to select account name and I would like the second DropDown List to automatically populates it's own values (Acount Code) sharing the same Account name based on the First dropdown list selection. Here is my sample code ...

```
<span class="label">
  <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Account Name"</asp:Label>
</span>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="name" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList><br />
<span class="label">
  <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Account Code"></asp:Label>
</span>
<asp:DropDownList ID="code" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

and my C# code is as follow ..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS))
                {
                    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT AccountName, AccountCode FROM Account", conn);
                    conn.Open();

                    name.DataSource = comm.ExecuteReader();
                    name.DataTextField = "AccountName";
                    name.DataValueField = "AccountName";
                    name.DataBind();
                    conn.Close();

                    if(name.Text != null)
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT AccountCode FROM Account WHERE AccountName= '" + name.Text +"'", conn);
                        code.DataSource = com.ExecuteReader();
                        code.DataTextField = "AccountCode ";
                        code.DataValueField = "AccountCode ";
                        code.DataBind();
                    }    
                }
            }
        }
```

In my case if i Change the Values of Account Name, the Account Code does not change automatically. How can i make that happen ..? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

to meet your requirements you will have to add two attributes to your first drop down (1) "AutoPostBack" and (2) "OnSelectedIndexChanged".

1) Autopostback will cause a postback when you select an item in the dropdown.

2) OnSelectedIndexChanged is an event you will have to code to fill the second dropdown.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="name" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="name_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```